# Text fields to lay above each other CSS

Tags: html, css, css-tables

For the past hour or so I've been trying t0 get these text fields to lay above each other.
After some Googling I tried some examples, they work for one part but not the other.
Here is my example in JS fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/53D5M/10/

I hope you see what I mean. The top half of the div will be the original message the bottom half will be the reply. I just want the subject input fields to lay on top of the textareas

I'm pretty new to this, sorry if it's something dumb I'm just not seeing.

Comment: Can you provide a visual example of how you want it, and how it looks on your browser? Which browser are you looking in?

Comment: can i ask for an image of how you would like it to be??

Comment: I'm working in Chrome, basically I'm looking for the input to be above the text area and submit to be below that as you can see in my jsfiddle theyre all laying next to each other

Answer (score 1):

All you're missing is a line break or another div after each field.

Simply:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type Subject Here" /><br/><br/>
<textarea rows="7" placeholder="Begin Typing Message"></textarea><br/><br/>
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

In this example I needed to add two line breaks (
) for the textarea to be pushed down enough. Normally, you can also put each form element in it's own `<div>` container

Comment: Yes exactly! Thank you! I didn't know to do it in the html, I thought it was some css I was missing! works awesome and I can accept your answer in 5 minutes.